# What's the limit of fraction inside square root

Tags: math, limits, fractions, sqrt

I need to find limit sqrt((3x-1)/(x+2)) when x->infinity

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I cannot get a rid of stupid fraction in the square root. -_-

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `sqrt(3)`:

As x gets very very big, the degree 0 terms (`-1x^0` and `2x^0`) grow insignificant thus leaving:

```
sqrt(3x/x)
```

As you can see this reduces to:

```
sqrt(3)
```

And this is no longer affected by `x` and is, then, the answer.

**Note**

Math questions are best suited on [Stack Exchange's Math page](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

mjgpy3 deserves credit for his correct and elegant explanation.

But I'll offer you Wolfram Alpha as a way to answer these for yourself without having to ask here:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%20sqrt((3x-1)%2F(x%2B2))%20%20as%20x-%3Einfinity

Comment: Great software, excellent for any math.